# MySQL - Order by numbers after string pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a column "host_name" in my table, with data like "sto11, sto9, sto8, sto13".
I need a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM hosts ORDER BY (numbers after "sto");
```

So the query returns data with this order: sto8, sto9, sto11, sto13

Is there a way to do this in mysql?

Comment: Is the prefix always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the prefix (sto) is fixed, you should cast a substring as unsigned, starting from the 4th element of that row entry. Something like this:

```
SELECT hosts.*, CAST(SUBSTRING(hosts.<column with order>, 4) AS UNSIGNED) AS orderednumbers 
FROM hosts 
ORDER BY orderednumbers;
```